# Desktop shortcut default action

Tags: shortcuts

I have a shortcut to a shell script on my desktop, and when i double click it the run in terminal/display/cancel/run dialog appears. Is there any way to set a default action for this dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you create a desktop launch icon for the file. Here is how:

1. Make sure your file is an executable, e.g. `chmod 755 myScript.sh`
2. Create a file on your desktop called `myscript.desktop`. The **.desktop** extension is important.
3. Open the file in your favorite text editor and append the following text:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=myScript
   Comment=Some Comment
   TryExec=/path/to/the/script
   Exec=/path/to/the/script
   Icon=/path/to/icon/if/you/wish
   Categories=Multimedia;
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   ```
4. Now, right click on the file -> Properties -> Permissions: Check Execute: Allow executing file as program.

Now, you would have a launcher on your desktop with an icon and everything. If you want Unity Dash to find it, just drop a copy of the file in `/usr/share/applications/`